# How to find difference in Java list?

Tags: java

I a having two string's

Here the `+` is missing after 5 characters so the answer is `+5|`. The logic I wrote has a problem when I use `list1.contains(s)` and if the number `s` is more than once then also index will increase and the wrong position will be saved as `+1|` which is wrong.

Here I am facing one more issue difference in list I am not getting the answer.

```java
String s1 = "7 + 8 = 7 8";
String s2 = "7 + 8 = 7 + 8";

List<String> list1 = Arrays.asList(s1.split("\\s+"));
List<String> list2 = Arrays.asList(s2.split("\\s+"));
int index = 0;
for(String s : list2){
    if(list1.contains(s)){
        index++;
    }else{
        System.out.print(s+index+"|");
    }
}
```

This function I created to find the difference, sometimes it returns the difference but sometimes it does not

```
    public static  <T> List<T> difference(List<T> answer, List<T> header) {
        List<T> toReturn = new ArrayList<>(answer);
        toReturn.removeAll(header);
        return toReturn;
    }
```

Comment: Don't use `contains()` as this will only find characters not present in the first list - as the name "contains" and the JavaDoc on that method indicates. Instead, you might want to use index based iteration, use `get(index)` on both lists to get the elements at that index and compare those elements. Of course you need to stop when you've hit the end of one of the list in which case all remaining characters in the other list are part of the difference.

Comment: Hi @Thomas if possible can you provide some sudo code example

Answer (score 0):

Your question indicates that a difference is not only defined by the elements being present in both lists but that their order matters too, i.e. `1,2,3` would be different from `3,2,1`.

Hence, don't use `contains()` as this only reports whether one list contains an element but doesn't take the order into account.

To find positional differences, you need to compare elements at the same index. Here's a simple example of what that could look like (note that this would be inefficient when using `LinkedList` in which case you'd better use an iterator).

```
<T> int findFirstDifference(List<T> list1, List<T> list2) {
  //restrict iteration to the size of the smaller list
  int smallerSize = Math.min(list1.size(), list2.size());
  for( int index = 0; index < smallerSize; index++) {
    T e1 = list1.get(index);    
    T e2 = list2.get(index);

    //objects are different, this is the first difference
    if(!Objects.equals(e1, e2)) {
      return index;
    }
  }

  //at this point the smaller list completely matches the start of the larger list
  //if there is a larger list the first difference is the index after the end of the matching portion
  if( list1.size() != list2.size() ) {
    return smallerSize;
  }

  //no difference found
  return -1;
}
```